# How do I get to label my table caption in colon?

Tags: captions

I have this table:
[image]

with the following codes:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Parametric values for Model 1 figures}
   \centering
      \begin{tabular}{|l| l|l |r|r|}
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\
    \hline
     Parameter & Fig.2 Value & Fig.3 Value & Fig.4 Value & Fig.5 Value \\ \hline
      $\alpha$ & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.6\\
      $\beta$ & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
      $\widehat{G}$ & 90 & 90 & 80 & 50\\
      $\widecheck{G}$ & 50 & 50 & 90 & 90\\
      $\bar{P}$ & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100000\\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \label{tab:Comparison of PV}
\end{table}
```

I want to get rid of the period in the heading and want to write: Table 1: Parametric values for Model 1 figures. Also, I want the caption to be a bit closer to the table itself.

Here is what I have in my preamble

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}

% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{;}{,}{,}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=normalfont,labelsep=colon}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{1}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \edef\@toclevel{\ifnum#2=\@m 0\else\number#2\fi}%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \@xp\let\@xp\@secnumber\csname the#1\endcsname\fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\@secnumpunct{%
      \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@ % not a run-in section heading
        \@ifnotempty{#8}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \else
        \@ifempty{#8}{.}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \fi
    }%
    \@ifempty{#8}{%
      \ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi}{}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{%
      \ifnum#2<\@m
        \@ifundefined{#1name}{}{%
          \ignorespaces\csname #1name\endcsname\space
        }%
      \fi
      \@seccntformat{#1}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@ % then this is not a run-in section heading
    \begingroup #6\relax
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty\@M #8\par}%
    \endgroup
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  \else
  \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\@svsec
    \@ifnotempty{#8}{\ignorespaces#8\unskip
       %\@addpunct.
       }%
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  }%
  \fi
  \global\@nobreaktrue
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\allowdisplaybreaks[4]

% Commenting/debugging
\let\IG\iffalse
\let\ENDIG\fi

%% Shortcuts
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand{\std}[2]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\ctd}[3]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d #2 d #3}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\spd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\cpd}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}

\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1/\partial #2}

\newcommand{\LR}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lg}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\eqp}{\phantom{=}}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\buildrel s \over =}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
```

Comment: There are a few bummers in zour preamble. e.g. `hyperref` should nearly always be the last package that is loaded. Also have a look at the booktabs documentation. There should be no vertical lines in tables and no horizontal lines between data. http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a "normal" font (instead of small caps) for the label and to get a "colon" (`:`) instead of a period, just change the preamble instruction

```
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=normalfont,labelsep=colon}
```

to

```
\captionsetup{labelfont=normalfont,labelsep=colon}`
```

That way, the `\captionsetup` directive will apply to *all* floats and not just to `figure`s.

To reduce the vertical distance between the caption and the `tabular` to a normal amount, simply delete the line `\multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\` from the `tabular`. To reduce the distance even further, you could add the option `skip=5pt` to `\captionsetup`. (The default setting is `skip=10pt`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}
%% I've condensed the preamble to the bare minimum needed for your example:
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{labelfont=normalfont,
              labelsep=colon}
\usepackage{mathabx}  %% for '\widecheck' macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Parametric values for Model 1 figures}
\label{tab:Comparison of PV}
   \centering
      \begin{tabular}{|l| l|l |r|r|}
    \hline
     Parameter & Fig.2 Value & Fig.3 Value & Fig.4 Value & Fig.5 Value \\ \hline
      $\alpha$ & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.6\\
      $\beta$ & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
      $\widehat{G}$ & 90 & 90 & 80 & 50\\
      $\widecheck{G}$ & 50 & 50 & 90 & 90\\
      $\bar{P}$ & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100000\\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I tried changing the caption setup at first, but it didn't then and now it does.