# Caption alignment issues with lstlistings environment inside lists

Tags: listings, code

The alignment of the caption of the my lstlistings environment for code is not correct when inside lists.

[image: incorrect alignment of lstlistings environment inside items]

The code to generate the image is given in the working example...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=true}
\usepackage{capt-of}

% create non-copy numbers (source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57160)
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand\donotcopy[1]{% line number printing mechanism
  \BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}%
}

% define colors for code blocks
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{codebackcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

% use listings for code block styling
\usepackage{listings}

% define style for code snippets
\lstdefinestyle{code}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!05},   
  commentstyle=\color{codegray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  numberstyle=\ttfamily\color{codegray}\tiny\donotcopy,
  stringstyle=\color{codegreen},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  breaklines=true,             
  captionpos=t,    
  keepspaces=true,
  numbers=left,          
  numbersep=5pt,            
  showspaces=false,        
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,             
  tabsize=2,
  frame=tb,
  escapeinside={!>}{<!},
  extendedchars=true,
  % Literate one-to-one mapping of numerals (source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153115)
  literate={0}{0}{1}%
  {1}{1}{1}%
  {2}{2}{1}%
  {3}{3}{1}%
  {4}{4}{1}%
  {5}{5}{1}%
  {6}{6}{1}%
  {7}{7}{1}%
  {8}{8}{1}%
  {9}{9}{1}%
}

% caption setup for code
% (source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117538)
\DeclareCaptionFormat{codecaptionformat}{
\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth\relax}{0.4pt}
\par\vskip1pt#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[code]{
  format=codecaptionformat,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  margin=0pt,
  font={sf},
  labelsep=period, % (Source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215884)
  labelfont=bf
}

% Creating the lstcode environment (Source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483721)
\lstnewenvironment{lstcode}[1][]
{%
  \def\lstlistingname{Code Snippet}%
  \lstset{#1, style=code}%
  % \clearcaptionsetup{lstlisting}% % This was in the example to prevent format mixing
  \captionsetup{options=code}  %
}%
{}

\begin{document}

Below is how this should look...
\begin{lstcode}[language=Python,caption={Listings Example}]
print("Hello")  # comment
\end{lstcode}

\begin{itemize}
\item Item text above the code
\begin{lstcode}[language=Python,caption={Listings Example}]
print("Hello") # comment
\end{lstcode}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**
I found out I can wrap these in a `tcolorbox` environment,eg...

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth, breakable, standard jigsaw, opacityback=0, frame hidden, sharp corners, enhanced, boxrule=0pt]
\begin{lstcode}[language=Python,caption={Listings Example}]
print("Hello World")
\end{lstcode}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Is there a way to combine both of these into a singular `code` environment (w/out using tcblistings)?

I tried...

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstcode}{\begin{tcolorbox}[size=fbox,breakable, standard jigsaw, opacityback=0, frame hidden, sharp corners, enhanced, boxrule=0pt]}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstcode}{\end{tcolorbox}}
```

and ended up w/ a working example...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=true}
\usepackage{capt-of}

% create non-copy numbers (source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57160)
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand\donotcopy[1]{% line number printing mechanism
  \BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}%
}

% define colors for code blocks
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{codebackcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

% use listings for code block styling
\usepackage{listings}

% define style for code snippets
\lstdefinestyle{code}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!05},   
  commentstyle=\color{codegray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  numberstyle=\ttfamily\color{codegray}\tiny\donotcopy,
  stringstyle=\color{orange},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  breaklines=true,             
  captionpos=t,    
  keepspaces=true,
  numbers=left,          
  numbersep=5pt,            
  showspaces=false,        
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,             
  tabsize=2,
  frame=tb,
  escapeinside={!>}{<!},
  extendedchars=true,
  % Literate one-to-one mapping of numerals (source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153115)
  literate={0}{0}{1}%
  {1}{1}{1}%
  {2}{2}{1}%
  {3}{3}{1}%
  {4}{4}{1}%
  {5}{5}{1}%
  {6}{6}{1}%
  {7}{7}{1}%
  {8}{8}{1}%
  {9}{9}{1}%
}

% caption setup for code
% (source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117538)
\DeclareCaptionFormat{codecaptionformat}{
\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth\relax}{0.4pt}
\par\vskip1pt#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[code]{
  format=codecaptionformat,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  margin=0pt,
  font={sf},
  labelsep=period, % (Source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215884)
  labelfont=bf
}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

% % Creating the lstcode environment (Source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483721)
\lstnewenvironment{lstcode}[1][]%
{
  \def\lstlistingname{Code Snippet}%
  \lstset{#1, style=code}%
  % \clearcaptionsetup{lstlisting}% % This was in the example to prevent format mixing
  \captionsetup{options=code}  %
}%
{}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstcode}{\begin{tcolorbox}[size=fbox,breakable, standard jigsaw, opacityback=0, frame hidden, sharp corners, enhanced, boxrule=0pt]}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstcode}{\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{document}


\begin{itemize}
\item Item above some coe

\begin{lstcode}[language=Python, caption={Hello World Example}]
print("Hello World")\end{lstcode}
\begin{itemize}
    \item More code
    \begin{lstcode}[language=Python, caption={Hello World Example}]
    print("Hello World")\end{lstcode}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item More code
    \begin{lstcode}[language=Python, caption={Hello World Example}]
    print("Hello World")
    \end{lstcode}
    \begin{lstcode}[language=Python, caption={Hello World Example}]
    print("Hello World")
    \end{lstcode}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

and the output...
[image: etoolbox fix]

So now I just need to fix the indentation and extra lines of code under lists...

**UPDATE**

The alignment issue goes away when I put the above fix in my actual document. The last problem problem is that the top of the tcolorbox is too big when there is a caption (shown below w/ frame).

[image: frame issues]

How can I fix this?